# Google Chat API returns a 400 response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chat

I created something like this:

```
function createRoom() {
   var accessToken = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";
   var roomName = "ROOM_NAME";
   var spaceMembers = ["SPACE_MEMBER_1@gmail.com", "SPACE_MEMBER_2@gmail.com"];

   var space = {
     displayName: roomName,
     memberships: spaceMembers
   };

   var url = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces?key=" + accessToken;
   var options = {
     "method": "POST",
     "muteHttpExceptions": true,
     "headers": {
       "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     },
     "payload": JSON.stringify(space)
   };

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
   Logger.log(response)
}
```

I defined the scopes and changed the project to be GCP
And the response I get is:

```
{
   "error": {
     "code": 400,
     "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"memberships\" at 'space': Cannot find field.",
     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
     "details": [
       {
         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
         "fieldViolations": [
           {
             "field": "space",
             "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"memberships\" at 'space': Cannot find field."
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

I couldn't figure out where the problem was
I apologize if my question is not clear because of my bad english
Thank you

Comment: Have you configured GCP?

Comment: Yes I have configured GCP

Comment: Where do you see that `memberships` is a valid entry in that structure?  https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces

Comment: You are right, I accidentally took it from the following link https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces/setup.
Should I delete the question or should you post this as an answer?